# How do I replace a URLLoader call with an ExternalInterface call?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

We have been given some code that does a `URLRequest` call which is really slow to respond, so I was looking to make it pull the data from the page, as it is already on the page.

```
//what we have
_dataLoader = new URLLoader();
_dataLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _eventTriggered);
_dataLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://somesite.com/xmlstuff.xml"));
```

I have tried to replace it with this (actionscript is definitely not my forte):

```
_dataLoader = new ExternalInterface();
_dataLoader.addCallback(_eventTriggered);
_dataLoader.call('some_function_returning_xml');
```

I am using `addCallBack` as that is what the editor suggested via autocomplete, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately I cannot go back to the developer at this time.

The error message is:

`Call to a possibly undefined method addCallback through a reference with static type flash.external:ExternalInterface`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExternalInterface is a static class. So you shouldn't create a new instance of it. Here's the fix:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback(_eventTriggered);
ExternalInterface.call('some_function_returning_xml');
```

Additionally, the method you "call" can return a String back immediately so you don't need to add a callback. Just return the XML as a String in Javascript and you get it as a String in AS3. Full Example:

```
// JS
function some_function_returning_xml(){ return "<result>Sweet</result>"; }

// AS3
var xmlStr:String = ExternalInterface.call('some_function_returning_xml');
var xmlData:XML = new XML(xmlStr);
```

ExternalInterface Docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks! Where do I define the js function in the project so I can fake the call to test it?

Comment: The SWF is being loaded into some HTML page (I'm not sure if you are using the Flash IDE, Flex, etc to generate the page), find that HTML page and add a <script>function some_function_returning_xml...</script> in the head.

Comment: It should be the HTML page you stated in your question >> "so I was looking to make it pull the data from the page, as it is already on the page."

Comment: Ah, ok, so I have to compile it to a `.fla`, then test it out, no mocking within the ide

Comment: No, no mocking with the IDE, you need to test it on an actual html page. What you can do (and is simpler in some situations) is to inject the JS code from flash... this way you don't need to create those functions externally. So you could do this: var xmlStr:String = ExternalInterface.call('function() { return "<result>Sweet</result>" }');

Answer (score 1):

You don't use ExternalInterface() as an object that you 'new'.  Instead it's a static class with some exposed functions.  Try this:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("some_function_returning_xml", _eventTriggered);
```

Answer (score 1):

ExternalInterface is a class that makes it possible to call functions in the containing environment, and as the other answers state, it's a static class.

You probably want something like this:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.call("your_javascript_function_name");
}
```

Or if you can even inject a javascript function and execute it immediately, by writing the javascript in the String:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    ExternalInterface.call("function(){alert('it works!');};");
}
```

The ExternalInterface.addCallback method allows you to expose an ActionScript function to the containing environment - so you could have JavaScript functions call ActionScript functions.